# Что обозначает "->" в данном контексте?

Tags: c++

```
auto isExpired = [](const std::shared_ptr<CTimer> &timer) -> bool
{
    return timer->isExpired();
};
```

Вопрос, собственно, о `-> bool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` в Вашем контексте означает тип возвращаемого значения анонимной функции. То есть указывает на то, что результат выражения `timer->isExpired()` должен иметь тип `bool`.

Указывать возвращаемое значение конкретно в Вашем случае необязательно. Компилятор может самостоятельно вывести его, так как тело функции содержит единственный оператор, и этот оператор — `return` (возвращающий выражение).

Если бы тело функции содержало несколько операторов, Вам пришлось бы явно указать возвращаемый тип. Потому что по умолчанию он был бы равен `void`.

Comment: Можно ли в данном случае чётко определить тип переменной `bool isExpired  ` вместо `-> bool`? Если не стоит, то почему? Дополните Ваш ответ, и я его приму. Большое спасибо!

Comment: я бы заменил слово "ожидается,"  на     "указывает"

Comment: `результат выражения timer->isExpired() будет иметь тип bool` иными словами, если написать `return 10;`, то выражение `10` имеет тип `bool`?

Comment: Включу душнилу. Нужно перефразировать: "означает **тип** возвращаемого значения анонимной функции".

Comment: @wololo Постарался перефразировать

Comment: @Artem.rtv, но вы можете вернуть и любой тип, который может и неявно преобразовываться  в bool. В принципе, в данном случаи можно и так. Но, в общем случаи, если хотите явно указать возвращаемый тип, то или так или  явно вернуть данный тип